# Onejar, with maven, won't copy resource into jar

Tags: maven

I'm using one-jar to package up my program.  I have resources in src/main/resources.  The maven-resources-plugin correctly copies the resources into the jar, but the jar produced by onejar does not contain my resources.

Here's my pom:

```
<project
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ziroby</groupId>
<artifactId>resourceTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>resourceTest</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>one-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
        <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I include resources in one-jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered my error. It was putting it in the jar, just not where I expected it to be. It's contained in a jar inside the main jar. Specifically, `resourceTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.one-jar.jar` contains `resourceTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, which contains my resource.

Now I just need to find out how to access the resource, but that's another question, which warrants more research.

Comment: Have you found out how to access this resource? Because i am stuck at this at the moment

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something similar to:
`getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`

Try instead using: `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`